# Extract NUnit logc to generate Test Book

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I would like to extract from my NUnit cases the description and asserts in order to generate a Test Book.

Example:

Create Account

- Assert ResponseStatus.Message is "OK"
- Assert User.Name is "Name"
- Assert Nationality is "US"

Code:

```
[Test, Description("Create Account"), Category("Account")]
public void AccountDocumentIDGet()
{        
   Assert.That (res.ResponseStatus.Message, Is.EqualTo("OK"), "Account was not created");
   Assert.That (res.User.Name, Is.EqualTo("Name"));
   Assert.That (res.User.Nationality, Is.EqualTo("US"));
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by _extract the name_?

Answer (score 0):

You can create own test for every case you want to assert

```
[Test, Description("Create Account"), Category("Account")]
public void ResponseMessageShouldEqualsOk()
{        
   Assert.That (res.ResponseStatus.Message, Is.EqualTo("OK"), "Account was not created");
}

[Test, Description("Create Account"), Category("Account")]
public void UserNameShouldEqualsName()
{        
   Assert.That (res.User.Name, Is.EqualTo("Name"));
}


[Test, Description("Create Account"), Category("Account")]
public void UserNationalityShouldEqualsUS()
{        
   Assert.That (res.User.Nationality, Is.EqualTo("US"));
}
```